# Static property access through an interface

Tags: c#, .net, interface, polymorphism

I honestly doubt this is the best way to approach this, but I have an interface defined as such:

```
public interface INamed
{
    string ExportName { get; }
}
```

And in reality I want these guys to all be static, but as it turns out you can't have static member declarations in an interface. So to get around that I implement the interface as such:

```
public class TestClass : INamed
{

    public string ExportName {
        get { return "Export Name"; }
    }
}
```

And I would go around accessing these guys by doing something like this:

```
public class Selector<T> where T: new(), INamed
{
    public string Output {
        get {
            string retString = "Selector of " + (new T()).ExportName;
            return retString;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to accomplish the same thing?  I really feel like I am doing something wrong if I am calling the constructor just to get at a static value.

Comment: What's wrong with public get / private set?

Comment: Oh I don't care if it's just a get, my big concern is about calling the new.

Comment: So...are you trying to do polymorphism with static classes?

Comment: that looks *smelly*, what exactly do you need that for? I bet you can refactor your code to not be forced to do something like this.

Comment: @contactmatt Not necessarily, I just want clean and consistent string representations of my objects for various operations, the code snippets I included in the question are just fragments of the actual machinations.

Comment: I think the best way in this scenario could be using attributes

Comment: @MichaC Well it's more for my GUI, right now it generates tool tips, comments and labels based on the INamed interface (there's more to it than in the question) and various other interfaces. So Selector is actually a GUI driving element that lets me select objects and describe what they are and how they work based on these internal strings.

Comment: as Clueless mentioned, Attributes would be a good alternative for you, just decorate your classes with CustomTooltipAttribute which takes a string value for example

Comment: @MichaC My only problem with attributes is I just love constraints on generic types. Is there a way to impose those on an attributes?

Comment: @xvpower - no way to do so.
you can always use an IoC container that might help you eliminate your problem but this is much harder to explain

Answer (score 4):

you can use attributes, since you are looking for class type information, attributes are the way to do this.

create:

```
   [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class|AttributeTargets.Struct)]
public class ExportName : Attribute
{
   public ExportName(string name) { this.Name = name }
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

and on the class:

```
[ExportName("The name you wanted")
public class TestClass
{

}
```

and on the selector:

```
public class Selector<T>
{
    public string Output {
        get {
      Attribute[] attrs = Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T));
      foreach(Attribute attr in attrs) 
      {
         if (attr is ExportName) 
         {
            ExportName a = (ExportName)attr;
            string retString = "Selector of " + a.Name;
            return retString;
         }
      }
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: My biggest problem with attributes is that they don't force me or others to implement them to utilize a lot of the generic classes (which is why I love constraints), and I am not exactly sure on the performance impact that reflection would have on a lot of my export classes that deal with thousands if not millions of objects. But I'll experiment with it a bit and get back to ya.

Comment: attributes are not stored per instance of your objects. It will be stored once per type, so don't worry regarding performance, it will be much faster than creating a new instance of your object and invoke a method because this needs much more processing...
Only way to enforce attributes is by throwing exceptions when they are not present... this is not very nice but might work...

Comment: @MichaC: New Attribute instances are created every time you call GetCustomAttributes. You have to cache the attribute yourself if you want to the performance gain. See http://dotnetpad.net/ViewPaste/u44XedD8y0-5UezAEdmN-w for an example